# Strange Company - What Am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I was struck with sudden inspiration for this original riddle.  I'm sure you puzzling pros will have this one solved quick.

A flightless bird is always my foe
A circus performer causes me woe
A mystery man is my enemy
A troublesome feline likes pestering me
All of these things are found in one place
I'm not embarrassed but I still hide my face

Who or what am I?  (The correct answer should also include what each line is specifically referencing.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> the fictional character Bruce Wayne, more commonly known as (the) Batman.

A flightless bird is always my foe

> The Penguin.

A circus performer causes me woe

> The Joker (made up more or less as a clown).

A mystery man is my enemy

> Cluemaster, perhaps? Or, n_palum plausibly suggests in comments, the Riddler.

A troublesome feline likes pestering me

> Catwoman, probably.

All of these things are found in one place

> Gotham City.

I'm not embarrassed but I still hide my face

> Batman wears a mask.

F1Krazy remarks in comments that the title

> may be a reference to Hugo *Strange*, another of Batman's adversaries.

Comment: Mystery man is probably the Riddler - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddler

Comment: Oh, yes, that's at least as likely as the one I put. I'm super-ignorant of this stuff and just looked up a list on Wikipedia...

Comment: The title might be a reference to [Hugo Strange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Strange).

Comment: Seems very likely, yes.

Comment: Well done!  And @n_palum was correct in his comment - Mystery Man was a reference to Mr. Edward Nigma (E. Nigma), aka The Riddler.

Comment: And I thought it was about an ostrich.